# How can I fix the BrokenProcessPool error in Qiskit?

Tags: programming, qiskit, simulation

I'm running a set of quantum circuits using the `ibmq_qasm_simulator`. However, sometimes my code works for the simulation, but sometimes it doesn't, and the system shows me the following message:

```
BrokenProcessPool: A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending.
```

I don't know why am I always getting this error. My Python version is 3.7.8, is there a way I can fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: This might be helpful: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/a/14581/9858

Comment: Were you using simulator or hardware? Could it be memory problem?

Comment: @KAJ226 Thanks for the comment! I've seen that post and tried all the methods suggested. I was using the simulator:)

Comment: Ah, I figured. Did you checked to see if it was a memory problem?

Comment: @ KAJ226  I didn't, how can I see that? Thanks:)

Comment: How big of a circuit were you running? Since you are using ibmq_qasm_simulator then you do have up to 32 qubits... so maybe it is not an issue... have you figured out anything yet? I am curious about this myself.

Comment: @KAJ226 My circuit has 8 qubits, but I'm doing 150 jobs for each running, and every single job has a list of 10 circuits. There's a Matplotlib command in my function, maybe that's the cause of my error, but sometimes it works, thats weird

Comment: Matplotlib might be the cause actually. look at this thread: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-ignis/issues/419

Comment: @KAJ226 Thank you!!